# How to Retrive Access Token in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get retrieve access token through code. I am unable to get that token, but if i try in postman under OAuth 1.0 I am getting access token.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a text editor not a programming language.